# PHP check if a date exists between 2 dates and then set a variable

Tags: php, date

I am trying to create a php script that when run will display a particular banner on a site based on the date.

The script generally works for individual days, but when I have a date range, then it picks the wrong day.

I am unsure if I have coded something incorrectly, or even if there is a more elegant way to code this.

In the code I have commented out $today = date("d-m-y") and added a secondary one so I can test the dates by manually changing the $today field.

I am relatively new to php and so am happy to learn better ways or even have my errors pointed out.

Thanks

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$banneroption = "";
$randomno = "";
$year = "";
$today = "";

//$today = date("d-m-y");
$year = date('Y');
$today = date('d-m-y', strtotime("30 april {$year}"));


//new year Jan
$prenewyear = date('d-m-y', strtotime("31 december {$year}"));
$newyear = date('d-m-y', strtotime("1 january {$year}"));

//vaentines day Feb
$valentines = date('d-m-y', strtotime("14 february {$year}"));

//easter week
$easterday = date('d-m-y', easter_date($year));
$easterweek = strtotime('-7 days', easter_date($year)); 
$easterstart = date('d-m-y', $easterweek);


//world oral health day March
$wohd = date('d-m-y', strtotime("20 march {$year}"));

//daylight savings ends clock goes backward
$dlsend = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first sunday of april {$year}"));
$predlsend = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first sunday of april {$year} - 3 days"));

//world health day April
$whd = date('d-m-y', strtotime("7 april {$year}"));

//anzac day April
$anzac = date('d-m-y', strtotime("25 april {$year}"));

//mothers day week May
$mothersday = date('d-m-y', strtotime("Second Sunday Of May {$year}"));
$mothersdaystart = date('d-m-y', strtotime("Second Sunday Of May {$year} - 1 week"));

//mens health week June
$menshealth = date('d-m-y', strtotime("second monday of june {$year}"));
$menshealthend = date('d-m-y', strtotime("second monday of june {$year} + 6 days"));


//dental health week August
$dhwstart = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first monday of August {$year}"));
$dhwend = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first monday of August {$year} + 6 days"));


//womens health week September
$womenshealth = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first monday of September {$year}"));
$womenshealthend = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first monday of September {$year} + 4 days"));

//fathers day week May
$fathersday = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first sunday of September {$year}"));
$fathersdaystart = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first sunday of September {$year} - 1 week"));

//ruok September
$ruok = date('d-m-y', strtotime("second thursday of September {$year}"));


//daylight savings starts clock goes forward
$dlsstart = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first sunday of october {$year}"));
$predlsstart = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first sunday of october {$year} - 3 days"));

//halloween October
$halloween = date('d-m-y', strtotime("last day of october {$year}"));



//melbourne cup
$melbcup = date('d-m-y', strtotime("first tuesday of november {$year}"));

//xmas

$xmas = date('d-m-y', strtotime("25 december {$year}"));
$prexmas = date('d-m-y', strtotime("13 december {$year}"));
$postxmas = date('d-m-y', strtotime("30 december {$year}"));


//commence show banner

if ($today == $newyear)
    {
        $banneroption = "newyear";
    }
elseif ($today == $prenewyear)
    {
        $banneroption = "newyear";
    }   
elseif ($today == $valentines) 
    {
        $banneroption = "valentines";
    }
elseif ($today == $wohd)
    {
        $banneroption = "wohd";
    }
elseif ($today == $whd)
    {
        $banneroption = "whd";
    }
elseif ($today == $anzac)
    {
        $banneroption = "anzac";
    }
elseif ($today == $ruok)
    {
        $banneroption = "ruok";
    }

elseif ($today == $halloween)
    {
        $banneroption = "halloween";
    }
elseif ($today == $melbcup)
    {
        $banneroption = "melbcup";
    }
elseif ($today == $xmas)
    {
        $banneroption = "xmas";
    }
    
    
elseif (($easterstart <= $today) AND ($today <= $easterday))
    {
        $banneroption = "easter";
    }
    
    
elseif (($today >= $predlsend) && ($today <= $dlsend))
    {       
        $banneroption = "dlsend";
    }


elseif (($today <= $mothersday) && ($today >= $mothersdaystart))
    {
        $banneroption = "mothers";
    }
elseif (($today >= $menshealth) && ($today <= $menshealthend))
    {
        $banneroption = "menshealth";
    }
elseif (($today >= $dhwstart) && ($today <= $dhwend))
    {
        $banneroption = "dhw";
    }
elseif (($today >= $womenshealth) && ($today <= $womenshealthend))
    {
        $banneroption = "womenshealth";
    }
elseif (($today <= $fathersday) && ($today >= $fathersdaystart))
    {
        $banneroption = "fathers";
    }

elseif (($today >= $predlsstart) && ($today <= $dlsstart))
    {       
        $banneroption = "dlsend";
    }

elseif (($today >= $prexmas) && ($today <= $xmas))
    {
        $banneroption = "prexmas";
    }
elseif (($today >= $xmas) AND ($today <= $postxmas))
    {
        $banneroption = "postxmas";
    }

else $randomno = mt_rand(1, 5);

if ($randomno == 1)
    {
        $banneroption = "temp1";
    }
elseif ($randomno == 2)
    {
        $banneroption = "temp2";
    }
elseif ($randomno == 3)
    {
        $banneroption = "temp3";
    }
elseif ($randomno == 4)
    {
        $banneroption = "temp4";
    }
elseif ($randomno == 5)
    {
        $banneroption = "temp5";
    }
?>  

<?php echo $today?><br>
<?php echo $banneroption?><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the exact issue? Please don't make us guess or having to run the code and look for the value that seems off. Is *all* of this code failing? If not, please reduce it down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Finding a cleaner/smoother/shorter way to do all of this should be a separate question for Code Review. Please try to focus on just one specific issue.

Comment: e.g. I set the date as 14 Februry 2021 in the $today field
The $banneroption comes out as "prexmas" rather than "valentines"

Comment: another e.g. if I set the date as 30 March 2021
$banneroption should be "easter" but it comes up as "postxmas"

Comment: For starters, `d-m-y` is not a format you can compare. You can do it with `Y-m-d` (uppercase Y explicitly), but I would recommend rather using `DateTime` objects. Next thing you have to check is if you have overlapping conditions, because you have specific dates and ranges. I would suggest placing this code in a function and returning the value as soon as you find a match. That way you can rank them by importance.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks for the feedback. What you have said makes sense. Like I said, I am new to php and teaching myself so this is great feedback.
 Is there something you can direct me to about creating a function for this type of procedure? I don't require a specific answer just direction

Comment: Nothing special to it, just instead of assigning in lots of `if-elseif` branches, you take the whole code and put it in a function, returning in the same places where you were assigning. A simple example: https://3v4l.org/dZQdW Other than that, I would recommend getting familiar with the [DateTimeImmutable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) class.

Comment: Your answer did the trick.  But I can't mark it as the answer

Comment: Because it's only a comment. You can answer your own question, though. It's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it was explained by @El_Vanja

Which was to set the time format at Y-m-d.

Still want to try the function but once I get that sorted I'll try adding it here.